# Triggering FancyBox from ASP.Net Codebehind

Tags: asp.net, jquery, fancybox

I want to use the JQuery FancyBox on an asp.net page but all the examples I have found show triggering a fancybox from anchor tag (< a >). I am not able to find an example where a fancybox is triggered from codebehind. 
To be more specific, I create a pdf file on the fly on a LinkButton click. After the file has been created, I want to show it using fancybox (I am using Jquery and FancyBox for the first time). Any examples showing how to do this will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Could you use a suitably constructed vbscript / javascript onload event handler to popup the box?

Comment: @Will, he would need to inject the script since it is not to load on `Page_Load` but rather after a `Button_Click`

Comment: Thanks Rockin' - I'll avoid offering advice on things I'm not totally comfortable with in the future.  :)

Answer (score 6):

after your linkbutton refreshes the page (postback), then you want to inject some script into your page.

Your page should have something like this already set

```
<a href="#" id="hidden_link" style="display:none;"></a>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function LaunchFancyBox() { 
          $("#hidden_link").fancybox().trigger('click'); 
    } 
</script>
```

Then you would inject some script at the bottom of the page from your button click handler.

So at the bottom of your page you will add something like

```
<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="Literal1" />
```

Then in your button click event handler you will have

```
Public Sub Button1_Click()
    Literal1.Text = "<script>$(document).ready(LaunchFancyBox());</script>"
End Sub
```

no.6 on their [blog](http://fancybox.net/blog) helps explain this as well, however they're launching it on page load ever time so they don't need to inject the script.  But because you want to do it on postback, you need to do the script injection bit.

Comment: Thanks for the reply rockinthesixstring, 
I am trying this, but getting a javascript error pointing at your first script i.e. in the LaunchFancyBox() definition. It says "Object expected". Sorry can't figure out what is wrong. 
By injecting script, you mean using ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript ?

Comment: no what I mean is you would put a literal control at the very bottom of your page that contains NOTHING on `Page_Load`.  Then when you click your button, you add a string `Literal1.Text="<script>$(document).ready(LaunchFancyBox());</script>"`

Comment: I've edited my answer. Sorry I can't test the script portion as I'm not in front of my IDE.  The concept is still the same however.

Comment: sometimes I forget the basics when I'm not in developer mode... :(

Comment: thanks rockinthesixstring and markt, but this is giving me a javascript error on page, saying "loading is null or not an object". In debug mode, it stops at: fancybox_abort = function() {
       loading.hide();
inside the fancybox-1.3.1.js

Comment: that's in your code somewhere. not sure where it's coming from since my example doesn't include `fancybox_abort`. Get your fancy box working as expected with the click of a button, then just replace the clickable button with the hidden button and inject the script that I sent.

Comment: it does work on the click of a button, but not when when I inject your code.
fancybox_abort is not in my code. It is inside the fancybox-1.3.1.js file.

Answer (score 4):

Solved. Just some minor adjustments to rockin's reply. Had to place

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#hidden_link").fancybox({
        'title'         : 'Test Document',
        'titleShow'     : true,
        'titlePosition' : 'over',
        'titleFormat'   : 'formatTitle',
        'type'          : 'iframe',
        'width'         : '98%',
        'height'        : '98%',
        'hideOnOverlayClick': false,
        'hideOnContentClick' : false,
        'overlayOpacity': 0.7,
        'enableEscapeButton' : false
    });
});
</script>
```

In the head tag, and Injected the code below:

```
protected void SomeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{          
    hidden_link.Attributes["href"] = "some_file.pdf";
    Literal1.Text = "<script>jQuery(document).ready(function() {$(\"#hidden_link\").trigger('click');});</script>";
}
```

Thanks rockinthesixstring for suggesting the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

I was using ASP.Net with VB.Net as code behind

ASPX:
1) I have a hidden anchor with style as display:none and no Literal
 Add hidden anchor tag id="hidden_link" clientidmode="static"  style="display:none;" class="fancybox fancybox.iframe"

In the content area or header:

```
 script type="text/javascript">
             $("#hidden_link").fancybox({
             //'title': 'Test Document',`enter code here
             //'titleShow': true,
             //'titlePosition': 'over',
             //'titleFormat': 'formatTitle',
             href: "SessioDocqReportPreview.aspx",
             'width': '98%',
             'height': '98%',
             'hideOnOverlayClick': false,
             'hideOnContentClick': false,
             'overlayOpacity': 0.7,
             'enableEscapeButton': false            
         }); 

     });
2) In the code behind button click event 
     Dim csMgr As ClientScriptManager = Me.ClientScript
     If Not csMgr.IsStartupScriptRegistered("OpenPopUp_Script") Then
       Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
       sb.AppendLine("$(document).ready(function() {")
       sb.AppendLine("$(""#hidden_link"").trigger('click');")
       sb.AppendLine("return false;")
       sb.AppendLine("});")
       hidden_link.Attributes("href") = "xyz.aspx"
       csMgr.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "OpenPopUp_Script", sb.ToString(), True)
     End If
3) This way we can get rid of Literal control, if still want to use the set the sb.Tostring to the text of the literal control with script tags and ofcourse remove the StatupScript.
BTW my fancybox is from www.fancyapps.com and v2.0.
```